# Problem with showing strings on textbox on forms, showing one at a time (async wait) C#

Tags: c#, winforms, twitter, tweetinvi

I got stuck on a problem for so long and I really need your help!
So my project is using Twitter API and my goal is to show specific tweets on win forms.
after using the API I'm getting an Array and each object inside the array contain a text section with the string that represents the tweet as you can see here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aorsY.png)

So I wrote :
textBox2.Text = tweets5[0].Text;
and each time the textbox shows one tweet at a time and I want it to show
all of them together on that textbox.

I tried to use for but the signature of the method is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEw0l.png)

I tried to print the length, tried foreach, tried while and
nothing seems to work...

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Well everytime you loop through your tweets5 array, your TextBox.Text will be replaced. You want the TextBox to show every Text of the tweets5 array?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm looking for!

Comment: [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can accomplish this. I'll suggest one:

You could loop through your array and append the text each time to a StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder AllText = new StringBuilder(tweets5[0].Text + Environment.NewLine);

for (int i = 1; i < tweets5.Count; i++)
{
    AllText.Append(tweets5[i].Text + Environment.NewLine);
}

TextBox.Text = AllText.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!!! 
The thing is I can only see 10~15 tweets on the text box (because of the size of it)
and after that, it shows another 10~15 till it shows all of them. 
can I somehow add a vertical scroll bar that will leave all the tweets without replacing them with others?

Comment: Could be a single like of code: `textBox2.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tweets5.Select(x => x.Text));`

Comment: What you have written, also adds an undesired new line at the end of the text.

Comment: thank you @RezaAghaei works perfectly!